# Javascript/HTML Storage Options Under File Protocol (file://)

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, file-uri

I am developing an html application that is essentially a series of pages like a book. Within this application, I would like to store several JavaScript variables across pages. Think things like pages read, bookmarks, etc. When this application is viewed over HTTP, I plan to use localStorage with fallbacks for older browsers (globalStorage, userData, etc.).

However, this completely breaks down if the files are accessed via "file://", for example if viewed off of a CD. It seems that most (if not all) localStorage solutions will not work under the file protocol. Cookies are not an option either under "file://".

**Any ideas on how to persist JavaScript data across html pages when they are being viewed via "file://"?**

It really only needs to be available in the current user session. I really don't want to use frames, but as of yet, I can't think of another way to accomplish this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A buddy of mine at work helped me out with this problem by sharing his implementation of using window.name to store data across pages of a single window/session.

A similar implementation (and discussion around the method) can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20200203061558/http://ajaxian.com/archives/whats-in-a-windowname

Preliminary tests I've been doing on this method look very promising. I tested this, under the file protocol (loading page from desktop, a.k.a. - "file:\") on the following browsers. It worked on all of them!!

- IE 6
- IE 7
- IE 8
- IE 9
- FF 3.6
- FF 4
- Chrome 11
- Opera 10
- Safari 4

I have not yet done any testing as to how much data you can store here, but *the internets* seem to agree on a value of 2 MB.

**Sources, links, more information**

- [JavaScript Programmer's Reference (Google Books)](http://books.google.com/books?id=XJrXl71TITIC&pg=PT472&lpg=PT472&dq=javascript+window.name+storage&source=bl&ots=X1_ibCwrN8&sig=9rZBZCdzP18yetVVKylQM4P3Wx4&hl=en&ei=3FzETaaIF4mCsQPRkembAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=javascript%20window.name%20storage&f=false)
- [Cookie-less Session Variables in JavaScript - Sitepoint Article](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/cookieless-javascript-session-variables/)

Comment: I've put together a demo of this (used to keep a persistent sidenav scrolled identically as you move from page to page): http://phrogz.net/tmp/data-through-window.name/ Tested to work with Chromev21, FFv14, IE8 and IE9 on both `http://` and `file://`

Comment: Great demo! I might suggest a fallback to `sessionStorage`. This would give you a little extra insurance in the event a future browser version decided to plug the `window.name` "hole".

Answer (score 3):

On Webkit (Chromium 12.0.742.21 dev-m) localStorage over file protocol worked fine to me.

On Gecko it's **[reported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=357323)** and should be improved soon.

You can even find a workaround, but I recommend that you develop using Chrome nightly build. So you'll not lose time moving it back to localStorage in future.

Comment: Is `storageSession` the different from `localStorage` or `globalStorage`? I thought Gecko left it out of `file://` on purpose.