# In IE10 ('localStorage' in window) condition is true but localStorage is undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, internet-explorer-10

Browsing all the questions/answers here but can't find a resolution to my problem. The condition `('localStorage' in window)` returns `true` but object of `localStorage` itself remains `undefined`. `<!DOCTYPE html>` set properly, can't get it working. I am using IE10. Tried watch it via developer tools, the same result.

Any ideas here?

Edit

```
function storageAvailable() {
    try {
        return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null && window['localStorage'] !== undefined;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Based on the same issue in IE9 I would like to update the question: ***is there any workaround?*** I cannot use even static server on the machine I need to test on.

Comment: You should post your code, as that's probably where the problem lies :)

Comment: The code is irrelevant i think, it is undefined even when just watching expression via IE debugger. But anyway adding my functions which returns false.

Comment: What is the url in your browser when you try to run this code?

Comment: The `try .. catch` here is completely unnecessary. There is nothing that will throw an exception, unless you shadow `window`.

Comment: Ah yes agreed, I just copied this function from some other thread here... originally it was without the last condition: && window['localStorage'] !== undefined; so it was returning true and then i got exceptions ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gonna go out on a limb here and say that your problem is that **local storage wont work on file:// protocol** in ie, so you need some kind of server.

Comment: That would be really unpleasant for the development, it is working in all other browser like opera, ff, safari, chrome ... But I must check that.

Comment: Fortunately these days it's a matter of two minutes to set up a local web server ;)

Comment: In my case, I just right-click any PHP file and choose my custom "Server (local)" menu item. How you go about it is up to you, but it's extremely convenient to have a feature like this. I implemented mine with a batch script.

Comment: [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is fairly common. Of course you could also use more simple things like command-line tools. If you need PHP, setting up a stack like xampp is worth the five minutes, though.

Comment: If the problem is local storage on the file protocol, you might want to look at different ways to store your data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914029/javascript-html-storage-options-under-file-protocol-file