# Is localStorage connection-dependent?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

I made a small JavaScript math game for my kids that stores a high score using `localStorage`.  It works fine, does what it's supposed to do, and saves the high score even when the browser is closed or computer is turned off.  However, today I tried to play the game for testing over a different Internet connection, and the two `localStorage` items I used (one for the score, one for the name) both returned `undefined`.

Both times the game was played in Chrome v55 in Windows 7 (same PC).  Originally it was over our home Wi-Fi connection, but today it was over a public (coffee shop) Wi-Fi connection.

`localStorage` still works over the public Wi-Fi connection -- I can set new values and retrieve them -- but I'm wondering why it didn't store the original values.  No browser history or cookies have been cleared.  Does anyone know if `localStorage` has separate containers for different Internet connections?

UPDATE: The `localStorage` object works fine -- it saves and persists data -- the only problem is that when retrieved when connected to a different network connection, it loses the values.

This is the code used to get data from `localStorage`:

`if (localStorage.mb_hiscore == 0) { localStorage.mb_name = " "; }
    hiscore.innerHTML = localStorage.mb_hiscore + "<br />" + localStorage.mb_name;`

Update again: Chrome shows the same origin on both the public Wi-Fi and my home Wi-Fi:

[image: origin setting, file]

Also, the `localStorage` values I set while on the public Wi-Fi connection persisted to when I retrieved them later, on my home network, so it's only the one time so far that Chrome dropped the values.

Comment: No, it does not.  I have to ask - where you using the same PC both times?

Comment: How are you accessing the webapp? Is it a local app (i.e. `localhost`) or over the network? If over the network, did you happen to switch IPs/domains to access the app?

Comment: is it possible you had a different browser session? EG private/incognito mode?

Comment: @Archer - yup, same PC both times

Comment: @Vinny - no, wasn't using incognito mode either time

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - it was a local app (file:/// protocol), the same protocol and file both times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript/HTML Storage Options Under File Protocol (file://)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914029/javascript-html-storage-options-under-file-protocol-file)

Comment: did the public wifi have a proxy of some kind?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - that question is different, it deals with `localStorage` not working at all with the file protocol.  It worked fine for me, just didn't seem to persist across a different connection.

Comment: If you're using the `file:` protocol, there's no network connection being used.

Comment: @freginold Whatever the reason, it was not because you had a different internet connection.  Go back to your original internet connection and the original data will still be gone.

Comment: @Barmar that's why I thought it was weird

Comment: @Archer gonna try that when I get home tonight, see what happens

Comment: @Vinny I believe it did use a proxy but I'm not that familiar with them and I'm not there any more

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Barmar there's really not much code to show; I'll update the question to include it

Comment: Seeing your update, if it happened only one time so far its probably some details that you've missed. Unless you come up with a way to reproduce your problem there's isn't much we can do.

Comment: @snolflake it looks to me like maybe a one-off.  I've since connected to both networks (home and the public Wi-Fi) and the `localStorage` values persisted.  Thanks for the info about origins, now I know more than I did before.

Answer (score 2):

Each origin has its very own `localStorage`. If you check the value of `document.location.origin` you may get something like this for example: "http://localhost:8080"

Depending on how you're accessing your app, if any of these parts change, be it the hostname, the port number or the protocol, you'll be dealing if a different origin therefore modifying its own storage. From the browser perspective is a completely different end point.

Try to reproduce your issue again, this time paying attention to the address you're using.

Comment: thanks, I'll check that when I get home.  checking the origin when I loaded the game while connected to the public Wi-Fi yielded "file:///" so I would imagine it would be the same over the other connection, since it's a local file, but I'll check just to be sure.

Comment: I checked the origin on my home network and got the same thing.  `localStorage` persisted from the public Wi-Fi to my home network.