# Persisting localStorage for WebView in macOS 10.11+

Tags: macos, webkit, local-storage

I have embedded a `WebView` in my macOS application and load a page in it. When users interact with the page, changes are stored in localStorage (as confirmed by making the same changes in Chrome), but it appears **WebViews do not persist localStorage** on macOS.

Earlier answers (years ago) indicate to use a private API which has since been removed entirely. Is there really no way at all to persist localStorage for a WebView in macOS? That seems crazy.

Comment: I should mention I do not own the site being displayed so I am unable to make any changes to it. It stores it's data in localStorage.

Answer (score -1):

Since I'm getting downvoted I thought I should see if I could improve my answer. here. This question seems to have a solution:
[How do I enable Local Storage in my WebKit-based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527905/how-do-i-enable-local-storage-in-my-webkit-based-application/4608549#4608549)

**Old answer that was not helpful:**

The following thread has a workaround that may or may not solve your problem:
[Javascript/HTML Storage Options Under File Protocol (file://)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914029/javascript-html-storage-options-under-file-protocol-file)

It suggests using window.name to store data across page reloads. It is not safe as the data is not isolated to your frame and could leak to other frames/tabs/domains but it may solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could always set up a simple CoreData store for the data changes and restore it to the WebView in ViewWillAppear.

And there is [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4853515/1491675) as well.