# Any alternative for JS storage under file protocol?

Tags: javascript, storage, file-uri

I am developing a HTML5 game, and would like to share it with file base.
So my friends can play it with a local html file (file://xxx.html).

However, most of the storage are based on the domain, such as localStorage.
I would like to know if there is any alternative to persist the game-progress-save under file-protocol?

I searched that windows.name may be the solution, but it can not store data after closing the browser.
[Javascript/HTML Storage Options Under File Protocol (file://)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914029/javascript-html-storage-options-under-file-protocol-file)

I also found the FileSystem API (Window.requestFileSystem), but seems only Chrome has implemented it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: An alternative is to bundle your game's HTML file and other assets with a small static-file webserver. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050851/best-lightweight-web-server-only-static-content-for-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- Bundle it by using Cordova or Electron
- Use Node.js + lite-server
- Use some free hosting service, my prefered solution would be Firebase as you would get a free yourGame.web.app domain, certificate and storage. You could set it up in less than an hour. To be honest, this is what I would do as it would be easiest for your friends to access the game too.

Comment: Thanks, seems there is no way to do it in pure JS. I will choose the Firebase suggestion. Thank you so much.

Comment: Good choice. If this answer is good for you please check mark it as correct.